# Vectors plot of electric field

Tags: vector, scilab

I trying to plot vectors of electric field in scilab. But it always error :

champ: Wrong size for input arguments: Incompatible sizes.

the code:

```
epsilon0=1e-9/(36*%pi);
q=3e-9;
p=[-1,0,0];
x=-2:0.2:2;
y=-2:0.2:2;
[px,py]=meshgrid(x,y);

for m=1:length(x),
    for n=1:length(y),
        xp=px(m,n);
        yp=py(m,n);
        vektorr1x=xp-p(1);
        vektorr1y=yp-p(3);
        r1=sqrt(vektorr1x^2+vektorr1z^2);
        if r1~=0 then
            ar1x=vektorr1x/r1;
            ar1y=vektorr1y/r1;
            E1x=q*ar1x/(4*%pi*epsilon0*r1^2);
            E1y=q*ar1y/(4*%pi*epsilon0*r1^2);
        else
            E1x=0;
            E1y=0;
        end,
    end,
end,
pl=champ(px,py,E1x,E1y,[-2,-1,2,-1]);
```

Comment: Where `champ` is what? I can't find reference to it as a built-in function, and if it's something custom then you haven't provided enough information to debug. The error seems pretty descriptive though...

Comment: @Wolfie https://help.scilab.org/docs/5.3.2/en_US/champ.html

Comment: I've removed the MATLAB tag, MATLAB and scilab are not the same language and this function does not exist in MATLAB

Comment: champ is a Scilab function (similar to quiver in Matlab).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use loops, the following script does what you want:

```
epsilon0=1e-9/(36*%pi);
q=3e-9;
p=[-1,0,0];
x=-2:0.2:2;
y=-2:0.2:2;
[px,py]=ndgrid(x,y);

vektorr1x=px-p(1);
vektorr1y=py-p(3);
r1=sqrt(vektorr1x.^2+vektorr1y.^2);
ar1x=vektorr1x./r1;
ar1y=vektorr1y./r1;
E1x=q*ar1x./(4*%pi*epsilon0*r1.^2);
E1y=q*ar1y./(4*%pi*epsilon0*r1.^2);
E1x(r1==0)=0;
E1y(r1==0)=0;

clf
champ(x,y,E1x,E1y,[-2,-1,2,-1]);
```

To plot fields don't use meshgrid to sample the domain use ngrid instead. Moreover, don't forget to use dot-prefixed operators.